# Alternative expression/term to trivial use of 'OCD'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

After being reproved for doing so myself on SO yesterday. I realized that over the last couple of years the meaning of the expression OCD, seems to have deflated. Up to the point where people(read I) mostly associate it with pet peeves like the price of a fill up at a petrol station and the amount of litres, [not both being round](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OpCd.jpg) or [misaligned street tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3B0V.jpg).

It is obviously very useful since most of us can relate to this feeling to some degree. However, in a slightly more formal context like SE, this obviously is not an appropriate word to use since its trivialises a very serious affliction and therefore might be hurtful to people suffering from real OCD.

What would be a viable alternative in a context like this?

Comment: My son says "I have CDO.  It's OCD only in alphabetical order, the way it *should* be."  (Consider saying "I'm maybe being a bit obsessive," or simply "It peeves me that...".)

Comment: (This isn't a phenomenon of "the last couple of years".  "OCD" has been used in a jocular sense for 20 years, at least.)

Comment: What @HotLicks says is right, OCD's not a new thing, it's just recieved more media attention in recent years because the TV corporations have realised that programs like 'Hoarders' and 'Obsessive Compulsive Cleaners' get good ratings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The cheapening of psychiatric terms is not restricted to OCD, look at what has happened to "psychopath". (Where I used to live, it has come to be identical with "ex-husband".)

As HotLicks says, we can go to its root with "obsessive", or if exercised on language (if the cap fits, wear it) we have **"pedantic"**. In general, "niggly" and "picky". Area51's "fussy" can also be a noun, namely **"fusspot"**, which I think our grandparents would have used for the people you have in mind.

You might like to speed-read Jane Austen for what she called ladies who absolutely had to have their toast *just so*, or early Hollywood biographies for stars who went postal if towels were wrongly laid out.

Comment: Pedantic is a good work, but why do you suggest it's specific to issues regarding language?

Comment: @Rikki: Because I think that's the principal application. OK, I could get pedantic about details of 12th century history, honest, but where?

Comment: A pedant is "a person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules or with displaying academic learning." (Google) Comic Book Guy on the Simpsons is a classic pedant. He is probably obsessive about his collection, keeping every issue carefully wrapped in plastic and in exact order, but becomes pedantic when expounding on his vast knowledge of minutiae.

Answer (score 8):

**[Fussy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/fussy)** could serve the purpose.

> too concerned or worried about details or standards, especially unimportant ones

[Oxford]

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you could use *anal*, for someone who has an obsessive attention to detail but I'd say that's stronger than just being *fussy*.

Source: [The Free Dictionary](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/anal+character)

Comment: Mhm, if you take the examples into account. Would you consider those anal personality traits?

Comment: A definition of _anal personality_ at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anal+personality) includes _"excessive orderliness, extreme meticulousness"_, so I believe these two apply to both your examples.

Comment: Yes I saw that. And it made me wonder. Since I wouldn't normally think that this is the best suited word for the occasion. However, I might be wrong.

Comment: You're probably right that it's a strong word but I'd say if somebody's personality consistently demonstrates _"excessive orderliness"_ and _"extreme meticulousness"_  then I believe anal is an appropriate term. I've seen it both self-applied and used to describe a third person. If somebody complains about the tiles in question, I know I definitely wouldn't call them fussy. Pedantic also seems appropriate, perhaps you can think of anal as a slightly more exaggerated version of it.

Comment: Of course, "anal" refers to the "anal-retentive" psychological trait (which my college psych prof explained fits the librarian who is not happy unless all the books in the library are neatly lined up on the shelves), so it's treading some of the same ground as "OCD".  That said, it's not unusual to hear someone say, eg, "Don't be so anal."

Comment: @Hot Licks: well, I guess the difference is that OCD is currently a medically recognized disorder, while "anal-retentive" is part of a mostly discarded system of psychoanalysis, so nobody can be diagnosed with the latter.

Comment: @sumelic - Of course, that raises another problem, in that fewer and fewer people know what "anal" means.

Comment: @HotLicks Not so much "not knowing what anal means", more "not knowing what meaning you are using it for"...

Comment: Because of the word's relation to a particular body part, calling someone else _anal_ is often considered pejorative. You can often only use it lightly to refer to yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I love the word "pernickety" (which is an alternative form of "persnickety"):

> **per(s)nickety**
>
> overparticular; fussy

Source: Dictionary.com

[image: Mr. Pernickety]

*Mr. Pernickety from the Mr. Men series*

Comment: _Pernickety_ is not a derivation of _persnickety_: it’s the other way around. (At least, the latter is attested earlier than the former.)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet:  Was that meant to be persnickety or did it just come out that way?

Comment: @Chellspecker If I were the spernickety type, I’d answer your question with the word “Yes”. ;-)

Comment: The fact that I'm commenting on this website confirms that I too am of the per(s)nickety persuasion.

Comment: +1 for "overparticular". It takes the mildly derisive edge off of "fussy"

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms associated with the trivial use of "OCD" tend to match the definition of *obsessive-compulsive personality disorder* (OCPD). Rephrasing the DSM-5 definition of OCPD gives several words for describing aspects of OCPD.

1. Legalistic; preoccupied with rules so as to lose the point of an activity.
2. Perfectionist; letting the perfect be the enemy of the good.
3. Workaholic; devotes self to work to the exclusion of leisure.
4. Purist, scrupulous, or inflexible about ethics, beyond what's expected from culture or religion.
5. Hoarder of goods; will not discard what fantasy author J. R. R. Tolkien called *mathoms*, things one keeps but does not use.
6. Micromanager; delegates tasks only when the patient can be certain that they will be completed to the slightest detail.
7. Miserly, stingy, or niggardly; hoarding money "for a rainy day".
8. Rigid or stubborn.

Also consider the word *fastidious*, which Wiktionary defines as "Excessively particular, demanding, or fussy about details, especially about tidiness and cleanliness."

Comment: Actually I think fastidious is an excellent example:). Especially for the everyday use. If always remembers me of the seinfeld episode [the Pothole](http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/ThePothole.htm). GEORGE: Finicky? Prissy? Fastidious?

JERRY: I'll take fastidious.

Comment: @laurisvr Actually finicky would also be a valid option I think:)

Answer (score 2):

My wife says, "Are you [Monk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_Monk)?" though that might fade from public consciousness since the show finished.

I think the TV show has made such affectations more readily shown in front of others, and seen as endearing rather than "strange".

Answer (score 1):

Being annoyed by misaligned tiles on the floor is *perfectionism*, the preference for perfection or some ideal. Such a person is a *perfectionist*, not suffering from OCD.

When your desire for perfection adversely affects your behavior, i.e. you are mentally unable to will yourself to enter a room because you saw one of the tiles on its floor is misaligned, then you might want to talk to a professional because you might actually suffer from OCD.

Answer (score 0):

**neurotic** fits pretty well.

[Google result](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=neurotic)

Comment: Hi Peter and welcome to ELU. This is a great answer, but you should consider adding a definition to it instead of a link.

Comment: Interestingly this also is a clinical term. Although it's not so much a disorder, but more of a symptom.